# Java: How to open JOptionPane with JButton

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, joptionpane

I got another question that would go to category "Java noobs" 
This time my problem is following: 
I need person to be able to click on button and it would display JOptionPane. However once I click on button it gives me exception.

My JButton:

```
    inputChar = new JButton("Guess Letter");
    add(inputChar);
    this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    inputChar.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    inputChar.addActionListener(this);



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if (action == "Guess Letter"){
        gl.getChar();
    }
```

Now my getChar() method is in different class and looks like this:

```
public String getChar(){
    inChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter (a-z)");
    if (inChar.length() > 1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Input is incorred, please input char", "Input warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    return inChar;
}
```

Exception triggers on the line `gl.getChar();`

And exception is following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Interface.ButtonPanel$1.actionPerformed(ButtonPanel.java:34)
```

Any Ideas how to fix it?

**EDIT NOTE:**

I managed to fix it with Loagans tip.
Basically in GuessedLetters class I just set constructors setters/getters and in action listener I put in method which sets them.

Problem Solved with following ActionListener:

```
    if (action == "Guess Letter"){
        inputChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter (a-z)");
        if (inputChar.length() > 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Input is incorred, please input char", "Input warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }else{
        GuessedLetters glr = new GuessedLetters(inputChar);
        glr.setInChar(inputChar);
        //For testing purposes
        System.out.println(glr.getInChar());
        }
```

Comment: Fix what? What exception you get?

Comment: Sorry, I might have explained it not clearly. JOptionPane pops up as soon as I start app, however, I want it to pop up only once clicked on JButton.

Comment: Are you sure what `actionPerformed` is the only place where you call `getChar`? It easy to check. Just print stacktrace to console at the beginnig of `getChar`.    `new Exception().printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Yeah it was reason why it kept popping, but now exception is on gl.getChar(); for some reason it doesnt want to complete action. And error message is very long. Look if I implement method inside action listener it works, but then how should I return value which was inputted inside the JOptionPane?

Comment: Please, post exception. It`s hard to solve problem without it. And mark in your code the row in which exception is thrown.

Comment: Alright, here, really dont know whats wrong with code =/ (Big Java noob)

Comment: I don't know which row is 34, but it seems as `gl` is `null`  when `actionPerformed` is called

Comment: row 32 is `gl.getChar();`
and gl is GuessLetters class object
`GuessLetter gl;`
`gl.getChar();`

Comment: Where do you initialize `gl`?

Comment: I initialize it inside action listener. Dont use it anywhere else.
If I initialize it in my main method, however, it works as expected, just somehow inside action listener it keeps throwing exceptions,

Comment: I don't see initialization of gl in posted code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for hints and tips, I managed to solve it! (w/o hints I wouldnt be able to do it =P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your main class is probably extending another class since you can call this.actionPerfomed. That means any action on your main class will trigger that method. What you should do instead is add an actionListener to your specific button.

You need to change the action == comparison to use the String .equals method since you are comparing string values. That == may be triggering the window on startup because both values are null and so it displays the window with a null pointer exception maybe?

Then here is how you would add an action listener to your specific button the user pushes.

```
    viewInsertFileButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            displayJOptionPaneHere();
        }
    });
```

So you only want to display the JOptionPane with an action is performed on that specific button instead of any actionPerformed on the main application.

I think this is causing the null pointer exception.

```
 if (inChar.length() > 1){
```

Before you call that, check if inChar != null. You can wrap your code inside of that, so it only calls the if (inChar.length() > 1 if it's not null to begin with. This is a common problem I run into all of the time, calling a method on a null object.

Change it to be like this and your exception should go away.

```
public String getChar(){
    inChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter (a-z)");
    if (inChar != null) {
       if (inChar.length() > 1){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Input is incorred, please input char", "Input warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       }
     } else {
          inChar = ""
     }

    return inChar;
}
```

You can protect gl from being null here too then.

```
if (gl == null) {
   gl = new gl();
}

    gl.getChar();
```

Comment: I need to return input value, and if I just put my method `gl.getChar()` gives me exception, if I just paste my method there it works, but I cant return input value then =/

Comment: Instead of returning a value from your Option pane, you can create a public setter in your main screen and the JOption pane can set the value using that setter. I think that will be easier to maintain than trying to return from the JOptionPane, because it also allows you to set multiple variables, where a return would only allow you to set 1.

Comment: I added more to my answer above to help you get around the null exception. You should still change your string comparison to use .equals though too.

Comment: its my `gl` initialization that is breaking it. (`gl` refers to another class object, class where sits my method) everytime i try initialize that object it throws exceptions, any ideas?

Comment: You can create gl when you declare it, or add a check for null in the code here, and if gl == null, then create a new gl(), else call the gl.getChar().